# Image Stitching using OpenGL ES in C

Tags: c, opengl-es, image-stitching

I want to stitch some images using OpenGL ES in C language. But I don't have much idea (only basic) about OpenGL ES and Image processing. I have checked on google for sample code. But I don't find any.  I can see some applications which uses OpenCV for stitching. But I don't want to use OpenCV in my application.

Does anyone have the sample code or If you have any idea on OpenGL ES functions which can be used for stitching please share.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, so this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.